# How do I close the current browser tab on ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I want the current browser tab to be closed on a click of a button. How do I implement this in ReactJS? Tried `window.close()` but did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example using the JS Fiddle feature in your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security purposes, JavaScript can't close a window that it didn't directly open.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

As you can see from the example, the originating script (which opened the window) must also be the script that closes the window. A new window isn't capable of closing itself via JavaScript.

```
//Global var to store a reference to the opened window
var openedWindow;

function openWindow() {
  openedWindow = window.open('moreinfo.htm');
}

function closeOpenedWindow() {
  openedWindow.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On your click event handler, try this :

```
window.open("", "_self");
window.close();
```